# ACF query posts where post object is NULL / false

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

The code below should hopefully make it clear what I'm trying to achieve. The key issue is with the second array in the meta_query. I am trying to find posts where the field 'alias' has not had a post_object set.

When running the query with var_dump( get_field('alias') ); the results returned are 'NULL'. I can't figure out how to query based on a NULL post object field. Pointers would be really appreciated.

```
$args = array(
    'post_type'         => 'event',
    'posts_per_page'    => -1,
    'meta_query'        => array(
        'relation'      => 'AND',
        array(
            'key'       => 'game',
            'value'     => 'baseball',
            'compare'   => '='
        ),
        array(
            'key'       => 'alias',
            'value'     => NULL,
            'compare'   => '='
        )
    )
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You're comparing it wrong. You can't check for `null` in `meta_query`. Try this:

```
array(
    'key'       => 'alias',
    'compare'   => 'NOT EXISTS'
)
```

This is basically the SQL way of saying `is null`.

Comment: Unfortunately this removes both the alias and the post object it's attached to from the query. I am looking to just remove the alias from the query.

Comment: Hmm, something very strange is happening with another field I have called "master_alias", which I was then using to amend post object query to show only available master_alias posts; I think your original answer is correct.